# How do I find the first column that contains more than 2 numbers in a range?

Tags: excel, vba

> **EDIT:** Clarified that row is formatted as GENERAL;
>
> **Expected result:**
>
> Cell that contains: "time: 02-06" ===== 4 digits
>
> Cell that contains: "date: 2019-11-29" ===== 8 digits
>
> Cell that contains: "Name1:" ===== 1 digits

I have a row that is formatted as "General" (shouldn't be changed). I'm trying to write VBA code that gives me the first column in the row that has more than 2 digits in the cell.

**Problem:**

IsNumeric doesn't work here since the cells are formatted as general and sometimes there are text, symbols, and numbers in the cells.

My guess is that IsNumeric will solve my issue better than inserting an array of possible values into a CountIf, but I'm not sure how to make isNumeric work here

**Attempt at Solution:**

```
Dim rRange as Range
Dim firstColWithNums As Integer
Dim i as Integer

'"Schedule" is a previously-defined named range that consists of only 1 row
Set rRange = Sheet3.Range("Schedule")

For i = 1 to rRange.Columns.Count
     if Application.Worksheetfunction.Sum(Application.Worksheetfunction.Countif(rRange(1,i),{"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"})) > 2 Then
          firstColWithNums = i
          Exit For
     End If
Next i
```

Comment: "I have a row that is formatted as "General"" together with "IsNumeric doesn't work here since the cells are formatted as text" seems to be inconsistent. Which is it?

Comment: What does it mean to have "more than 2 numbers in the cell." Do you mean that the cell contains a *string* such as '"123, 456,789"`? If so, what is the format of these strings? This question isn't very clear.

Comment: Also, your code seems to be trying to count *digits* rather than *numbers*. Would something like `"123"` count as 1 (number) or 3 (digits)?

Comment: @JohnColeman Ah sorry about the confusion. Thought they were the same. The cells are formatted as "General"

Comment: Also, yes. I mean to just count the number of digits there are. For instance, if the cell contains "time: 06-08", the count should be 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a function to count the number of digits in a string

```
Option Explicit

Function numberDigits(inp As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim res As Long

    For i = 1 To Len(inp)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(inp, i, 1)) Then
            res = res + 1
        End If
    Next i

    numberDigits = res

End Function
```

And then I adjusted your code like that

```
Sub codeOfOP()
    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim firstColWithNums As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    '"Schedule" is a previously-defined named range that consists of only 1 row
    Set rRange = Sheet3.Range("Schedule")

    For i = 1 To rRange.Columns.Count
        'if Application.Worksheetfunction.Sum(Application.Worksheetfunction.Countif(rRange(1,i),{"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"})) > 2 Then
        If numberDigits(rRange(1, i)) > 2 Then
            firstColWithNums = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked for me - was hesitant to add a new function but the readability of the code is probably going to help with debugging later!

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding...
Format is General, data should come from an external source so it should be considered as string.

Try this one.

```
Dim rRange as Range
Dim firstColWithNums As Integer
Dim i as Long
Dim j as Long
Dim Test as string

'"Schedule" is a previously-defined named range that consists of only 1 row
Set rRange = Sheet3.Range("Schedule")
firstColWithNums = 0

For i = 1 to rRange.Columns.Count
    Test = rRange(1,i).Value2
    For j = 1 to Len(rRange(1,i).Value2)
        If (IsNumeric(Mid(Test, j, 1) = True) and (firstColWithNums < 1) Then
          firstColWithNums = 1
        ElseIf (IsNumeric(Mid(Test, j, 1) = True) and (firstColWithNums = 1) Then
          firstColWithNums = i
          Exit For
        End If
    Next 'j 
    If (firstColWithNums <> 0) and (firstColWithNums = i) then 
        Exit For
    Else
        firstColWithNums = 0
    End If
Next 'i
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You need to "reset" `firstColWithNums` outside of the `j` loop or it will trigger as the second numeric is found (2 cells with 1 numeric will also trigger). And in general: do not exit loops by changing the iterator (always treat it as "read only" as it can lead to unpredictable behavior).

Comment: @Dirk Reichel. You are right regarding the reset, I already edit it. Regarding the iterator... I change it, but I never have any problem with it if you follow the same sequence... How can it fail?

Comment: It is more a general thing… It does work here, but at some point, you may fail with it at other languages which can happen if you are using external applications (just make it a habit to do it the correct way). But much more important: it hurts the readability pretty much. An `Exit ...` is self explaining and if you need to alter the code later on you will spot it in an instant even without comments. (So it is just my advice to always use the correct boring long way) ;)

Answer (score 1):

> *"I'm trying to write VBA code that gives me the first column in the row that has more than 2 numbers in the cell"*

I agree with the comments that your above statement does leave room to interpretate what you consider "numbers". But in case what you are after is just to know if two or more characters in the string value are actually considered numeric values, then try to replace your loop through the columns with:

```
For i = 1 To rRange.Columns.Count
     If Application.Evaluate("SUM(LEN(" & rRange(1, i).Address & ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" & rRange(1, i).Address & ",{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},)))") > 2 Then
          firstColWithNums = i
          Exit For
     End If
Next i
```

Or rather, refer to the correct sheet using `.Evaluate` through a `With..` statement:

```
With Sheet3
    Set rRange = .Range("Schedule")
    For i = 1 To rRange.Columns.Count
        If .Evaluate("SUM(LEN(" & rRange(1, i).Address & ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" & rRange(1, i).Address & ",{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},)))") > 1 Then
            firstColWithNums = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

`ISNUMERIC` will return `TRUE` for empty cells.

Here's another method that looks only for digits using Regular Expressions.

Note that we only check the first row of the range fed to the function, but you can use error checking or other logic if that is not what you want.

```
Option Explicit
Function firstWith2Digits(rw As Range) As Long
    Dim RE As Object, MC  As Object
    Dim C As Range
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "\d"
    .Global = True
    For Each C In rw.Rows(1).Cells 'only check first row
        Set MC = .Execute(C.Value2)
        If MC.Count >= 2 Then
            firstWith2Digits = C.Column
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next C
End With

End Function
```

Comment: Hmm… I'm curious… which single non-digit character is considered "numeric"?

Comment: @DirkReichel I was incorrect in that statement.  An empty cell will return `TRUE` for that test, but not other single non-digit characters. Thanks for catching that.